# How can I import Material UI icons?i met some problems using Material ui icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) with React in my project, and I had some troubles when it came to import the [material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) icons. My code is copied from the Material UI (version:"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.41",
"material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",)
docs ,just like this:

```
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious';
import PlayArrowIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow';
import SkipNextIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SkipNext';
```

And I have also run `npm install material-icons`.

The error in my Chrome console is:

> ./src/index/musicCard.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> '@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow' in
> 'C:\Users\wenji\Desktop\myblog\src\index'

And I tried this one:

```
import SkipPreviousIcon from 'material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious';
```

And this one:

```
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@material-ui-icons/SkipPrevious';
```

But it does not make any difference. How can I fix it?

Comment: Which module loader do you use? Can you post the configuration of your module loader? Did you insert the configuration for this module? The problem is with "@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow" and not with "material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious"

Comment: my project was created by react-creat-app ,i almost did not change the default config except a babelloader:`{
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react','stage-0'],
        
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },`

Comment: Then you have to edit the configuration and add the path to @material-ui/icons/PlayArrow

Comment: Do you mean create-react-app from facebook?

Comment: emm,can you give me more details？ thanks a lot

Comment: yeah,the facebook cli,react-create-app

Comment: Did you use create-react-app from facebook? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app I can't find anything about react-create-app

Comment: sorry, exactly the name is create-react-app

Answer (score 94):

Icons are not part of *material-ui/core*, so it must be installed using two commands.

If you are using [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)):

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

If you are using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```
yarn add @material-ui/core
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans!!. Working Perfectly.

Answer (score 24):

The icons module should be added to dependencies.

Use npm

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

Or use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)

```
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

Answer (score 16):

For the latest versions you need

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Since [Material-UI is now MUI](https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/).

And if we need a specific icon, we can get like,

```
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SkipPrevious';
```

And here are [all available icons](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/).

Comment: Those who are using the latest version of Material-UI please use this to fix the error

Answer (score 5):

I just solved a strange (but not so strange after I found out why) issue.

On Mac, it worked, but when I deployed to Linux, it failed and could not find the icon.

This was because on Mac it was not case sensitive and on Linux was.

So

```
import DeleteForEver from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteForEver'
```

works on Mac, but it fails on Linux.

The file is actually named like "DeleteForever".

So the correct way to import is:

```
import DeleteForever from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever'
```

Comment: You just saved my life. I had no idea why my project works perfectly on my Mac but fails when I deploy to Jenkins.
In my case I looked at the Material UI docs where the example I copied was all lower case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the import path from `@mui/icons-material/` to `@material-ui/icons/`

This is not a 100% working solution, as there have been icons I have yet to be able to import (e.g. `ConnectWithoutContact`)

Regardless, this change has saved me several times so here is an example:

```
// Initial
import PermContactCalendarIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PermContactCalendar';

// Fixed
import PermContactCalendarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PermContactCalendar';
```

Answer (score 1):

Material UI doesn't provide icons from **"@material-ui/icons"** any more. Instead, you need to import icons from **"@mui/icons-material"**. So, if you are using the latest version and running your project with **npm**, you need to execute the following command:

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

If you use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), then run the following:

`yarn add @material-ui/icons`

Now you are all set to use your Material icon **ExampleMaterialIcon** like this:

`import ExampleMaterialIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExampleMaterialIcon';`

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.3",
```

Example:

```
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import ShareIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Share";

 <FavoriteIcon
            fontSize="large"
            style={{ fill: "red", stroke: "red" }}
  />

 <ShareIcon fontSize="large" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but fixed it this way: navigate to
[material-ui/icons](https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/) , search and click on the icon and you will find the right import syntax,
eg. `import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';`

now [npm install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons) `npm i @material-ui/icons` or `yarn add @material-ui/icons`
the package depending on your package manager, this should fix the bug accordingly.